# Can't preview embedded Figma canvas on Markdown

Tags: visual-studio-code, canvas, markdown, figma

How do I embed a Figma canvas on a GitHub Markdown (Readme.md)?
I have tried copy-pasting the Embed code but when I try to preview it in VsCode, I get the message:

`Some content has been disabled in this document`

Answer (score 1):

GitHub Flavored Markdown strips many HTML elements and properties due to security concerns. You can include an image, but not a canvas.

Comment: What about a regular markdown? I still get the error

Comment: Probably same reasoning (security), but this time by VS Code.

Comment: Would you happen to know a fix?

Comment: Googling `vs code markdown preview security` yields: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/markdown#_markdown-preview-security which is probably the best answer to that question.